# Format Seaborn x axis to MM/DD/YYYY Format

Tags: python, seaborn

I am wondering how to format my X axis : Currently my axis looks like as follow :

[image]

The dream would be to get :

[image]

Strugling with this, I tried to convert my Date array to other formats but still does not work.

Currently My array is :

```
DateList = np.array(list(MaVar['Dates'].tail(6)))

Print(DateList)
-------------
[Timestamp('2021-09-30 00:00:00') Timestamp('2021-10-31 00:00:00')
 Timestamp('2021-11-30 00:00:00') Timestamp('2021-12-31 00:00:00')
 Timestamp('2022-01-31 00:00:00') Timestamp('2022-02-28 00:00:00')]
```

The code where I set x axis is below :

```
sns.heatmap(MatrixData, xticklabels=DateList)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the dates from the Timestamps with [`dt.date`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
DateList = np.array(list(MaVar['Dates'].dt.date.tail(6)))
```